# jQuery wrap an element after replaceWith method but not work

Tags: jquery, replacewith

I tried to wrap a `div` after replace the original element from `div` to `input` but not work, could anyone suggest what wrong with my code below, thanks.

```
$('.sth').replaceWith(
    $('<input>', {
        value: $('.sth').text(),
        type: 'text'
    })
).wrap('<div class="new" />');
```

Demo:
http://jsfiddle.net/zhmUK/1/

Comment: Chaining problem, replaceWith doesn't return the input, see your updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/zhmUK/6/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

http://api.jquery.com/replaceWith/

> Replace each element in the set of matched elements with the provided
>   new content and return the set of elements that was removed.

```
$('.sth').replaceWith(
    $('<input>', {
        value: $('.sth').text(),
        type: 'text'
    }).wrap('<div class="new" />').parent()
);
```

Comment: Why put `parent()` after `wrap()`?

Comment: @CharlesYeung,  `wrap` doesn't return the wrapping element, but the element wrapped.

Answer (score 2):

`replaceWith` returns your removed `.sth` element . Citation:

> The .replaceWith() method, like most jQuery methods, returns the
>   jQuery object so that other methods can be chained onto it. However,
>   it must be noted that the original jQuery object is returned. This
>   object refers to the element that has been removed from the DOM, not
>   the new element that has replaced it.

So you're wrapping the wrong element, element that is not in the DOM anymore.

From here: http://api.jquery.com/replaceWith/

Answer (score 1):

you can try

```
$('.sth').wrap('<div class="new" />').replaceWith(
    $('<input>', {
        value: $('.sth').text(),
        type: 'text'
    })
);
```